# how can I find equation variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have the following equations :

$$\begin{cases}K = \frac{B – 3}{20}\\
 K = (20S+3)R+S\\
 K = 20S^2 + (20N+7)S + N\\
 N=S-R
\end{cases}$$
 - And I have the $B$ values, e.g : 173, 283, 2343, 834343

**How can I find the $R$ values?**

Another question: Can I re-write these equations as one equation (I want to use computer programming to find $R$ values) where the $R$ is the result and the $B$ is the variable?

Comment: 4 equations should be reduced to 2. Already they can be solved even without a computer.

Comment: I know that we can solve these equations and get the R values, but I'm not an expert in the mathematics field, can you show me the steps for one example (let’s say  B is 2343)?

Comment: @Kumar: See my answer. If I'm not mistaken, you'll get $R\approx -2.4812,2.3562,117.25$ for $B=2343$ by WA.

Comment: @mathlove: thank you for quick response. can you show me how you found the R values for B (2343)?

Comment: @Kumar: I just used Wolfram alpha. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16000+R%5E3%2B%28400-%28800%29%282343%29%29+R%5E2%2B%28-80-%28140%29%282343%29%29+R%2B2%282343%29%5E2-5%282343%29-3+%3D+0

Comment: @mathlove: Nice online app, but I need math methods because I have large numbers (as example: 10^87653 + 21)

Comment: @Kumar: I showed an equation for $R$ in my answer. So, why don't you use 'computer programming' you mentioned in the question?

Comment: @mathlove: how can I use programming with your equation?? I need equation can convert to code. as example: R = B^2 + B + ......

Comment: @Kumar: You can get $R=\cdots$ form if you want. see the following page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have
$$K=40S^2+(8-20R)S-R$$
$$\iff K=40\left(\frac{K-3R}{20R+1}\right)^2+(8-20R)\cdot\frac{K-3R}{20R+1}-R$$
$$\iff K(20R+1)^2=40(K-3R)^2+(20R+1)(8-20R)(K-3R)-R(20R+1)^2$$
$$\iff 20K(20R+1)^2=800(K-3R)^2+20(20R+1)(8-20R)(K-3R)-20R(20R+1)^2$$
$$\iff \color{red}{20K}(20R+1)^2=2(\color{red}{20K}-60R)^2+(20R+1)(8-20R)(\color{red}{20K}-60R)-20R(20R+1)^2$$
$$\iff \color{red}{(B-3)}(20R+1)^2=2(\color{red}{B-3}-60R)^2+(20R+1)(8-20R)(\color{red}{B-3}-60R)-20R(20R+1)^2$$
$$\iff 16000 R^3+(400-800B) R^2+(-80-140B) R+2B^2-5B-3 = 0.$$